# How can I access an ASP.Net 2.0 web service using VB Script?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, vbscript, asmx

I'm trying to find a way to access a web service from a VB Script .vbs file running under wscript.exe.  I pulled some sample code from Microsoft and modified it to use the SOAP 3.0 toolkit but it gives me an error.

```
Dim SOAPClient
Set SOAPClient = createobject("MSSOAP.SOAPClient30")
SOAPClient.mssoapinit("https://www.domain.com/Folder/Service.asmx?WSDL")
```

On that last line I get an error message:

> WSDLReader: Could not find '/definitions' inside the default WSDL namespace
>   HRESULT=0x80004005: Unspecified error
>   - WSDLReader:Loading of the WSDL file failed HRESULT=0x80004005: Unspecified error
>   - Client:One of the parameters supplied is invalid. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.

The reason it needs to be in VB Script is because it's going to be used in a program over which I have no control and that program only supports VB Script.  Is there a way to get VB Script to be able to parse a newer WSDL file?

I do have the source code for the web service though I didn't write it myself.  Is there something I can change in the web service to make it schema compatible with the SOAP toolkit 3.0?  I can use this web service from a .Net app with no trouble at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why not writing a managed component that will consume the web service and [expose it as COM component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6.aspx) which your script might consume?

Comment: Only because this was supposed to be a quickie solution to a problem, not a major development effort.  I agree that is a viable workaround.  I know that wouldn't take too long but it would take longer that writing a quick vb script.  If we can't get the script working with the web service then I'll see if my client wants me to take the time to write a "bridge" for the script to use.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the `<webServices><protocols>` section of the web.config for your service to see whether it is supporting SOAP 1.1 or 1.2. The SOAP Toolkit predates SOAP 1.2 and may not understand it.